# wso2iot-3.1.0: Real time location track on analytics dashboard

Tags: wso2, location, tracking, iot

Can someone explaine me step by step how configure location tracking with WSO2 iot 3.1.0 analytics for 1000 android and mobiles devices?

We have a lot of tecniciens working on fields and we need  to track them when they are out of their itinaries or not. We have several groups of techniciens across the country.
My hope is to have  several custom reports base on location  with devices and tecniciens intinaries on an Analytics dashboard. When the guy is out of the zone, I receive alerte message.

I have a plateform with  wso2iot-3.1.0-update1, running on 1 server OS: Centos 6.7 .
The geofencing is activated in devicemgt (In zone, out of zone, )
I'm still using the default  open sreet map 
Devices are already in device management and users accounts but when we clic on location of a device, the itinary is not well adjusted to the map.

is it possible to do this with open street map or I must used google map and how?

Notice that is for real time tracking.

Documenttaion used:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Monitoring+Devices+Using+Location+Based+Services
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Understanding+the+WSO2+IoT+Server+Analytics+Framework

Thanks in advance

Comment: With the current geo fencing capabilities you might need to create geo-fences per device. We are in the process of adding group capabilities into geo fences which means you will be able to define geo fences into a group of devices. This feature will shipped with the WSO2 IoT Server 3.1.0-update6.

Comment: Please Rasika , can I have a date of  new Update6 release ?Also we have DAS' report (geo alert location), base on widget created with bash reports. How can I add legend on colors,  phone number or username? To make the report more usable by business team. Something like picture 7 of the link bellow: https://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/tag/analytics/ . Regards